# PHP Scope and global

Tags: php, scope, global

im a bit confused about the scope of variables in PHP. I have read through the sections about scope, GLOBALS and global in the PHP manual, but this doesnt seem to hold true in the application I'm building. At the beginning of the page i am setting a variable like this

`$vars = array(
   'id' => '2',
   'name' => 'john'
);`

Then later i want to use this in a function, so i go:

`function my_func() {
    global $var;
    foreach ($vars as $var) {
    echo $var;
    }
}`

But this wont work unless i also put a `global $vars`in front of the first time i set the variable - do i really need to but this global at both places? or what am i doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globals are messy imo and hard to debug, pass it as an argument to your function.

```
$array = array( 'id' => '2', 'name' => 'john' );

function my_func($vars) {
    foreach ($vars as $var) { 
        echo $var; 
    } 
}

my_func($array);
```

Comment: Thanks! so how does that chain work then? the initial var gets passed to the function call, and then on to the actual function and then to the foreach?

Comment: The function is predefined. When you pass the variable through the function arguments it is then available inside the scope of the function to do as you wish. I've renamed the variables so you can understand it better.

Comment: @Malthe Milthers Sounds like http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

Typo.

`global $var;` should be `global $vars;`

Comment: A valid solution but please use the other solutions with hint on how to NOT use globals.

Comment: ToBe is right. I was just pointing out why your code wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

What you *actually* doing wrong - is using global variables. Never do that because global variables are side-effect. They produce cases that may be extremely hard to debug. Imagine that you have function in 143-th included file that somewhere in 2056-th line changed your variable occasionally, which also causes breaking of all your logic.

So, really, **pass variables as parameters**:

```
function my_func($vars) 
{
   foreach ($vars as $var) 
   {
      echo $var; 
   } 
}
```

As for your code - first, use whitespaces. Really - for interpreter and compiler they do not matter, but for humans that will read that code it's extremely important to see clear picture.

And your error is that you're trying to access global variable which is your loop iterator and that makes no sense, since your global variable is your *array*, not temporary loop iterator.

I hope my quick code review will be helpful for you.